# BigQuery SQL WHERE Date Between Current Date and -15 Days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to code the following condition in the `WHERE` clause of SQL in BigQuery, but I am having difficulty with the syntax, specifically *date* math:

```
WHERE date_column between current_date() and current_date() - 15 days
```

This seems easy in MySQL, but I can't get it to work with BigQuery SQL.

Answer (score 54):

Use [DATE_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_sub)

```
select * 
from TableA
where Date_Column between DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) and current_date()
```

Remember, `between` needs the oldest date first

Comment: I get this error `No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATETIME, DATE, DATE. Supported signature: (ANY) BETWEEN (ANY) AND (ANY) `

Comment: @urwaCFC I had the same issue. My guess is date_column is not type date, in my case it was type Timestamp. Try: Date(date_column) between current_date()...

Comment: @UrvahShabbir for timestamp you can use the similar operator than date, for example:

`WHERE Date_Column BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 13):

You should probably switch the two around - the syntax should be the following:

```
WHERE date_column BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -15, 'DAY') AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Comment: The DATE_ADD version works.  DATE_SUB is not supported in bigquery

Comment: DATE_SUB version now works if you use standard SQL in bigquery.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
WHERE DATE(date_column) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -15, 'DAY'))
AND CURRENT_DATE()
```